Google forms prefill url with current date and time or script or ai
Essentially what im trying to do is make it so the entry field of my form for the date and time gets autofilled with the current date
I do know theres a script editor but i have no idea how to make it so the year month and date gets filled "${dateEntryFieldID}=${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}"
Or if someone knows how to make it so the URL can have dynamic number for the current date/time and not a static one that would also work (No idea how to do that outside of hosting a site that modifies the url and auto forwards)
I also thought what if theres a add on (ai or not) that can also do the job
(The main reason i want this is because i have a form for attendance and those 2 fields are annoying but required by people above me because stats, but i want to make it easier and faster on the user)
I tried to modify the url and i know it workd but idk how or were to get the data from so it auto paste into the url dynamic. and i did try o search for some ai addon but atleast the few that i tried didnt have autofill
I also did try the guides from other post but there a bit outdated and dont help with my solution

Does this answer your question? How to set default date to today in google form?

I do know theres a script editor but i have no idea how to make it so the year month and date gets filled "${dateEntryFieldID}=${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}"
Google Forms does NOT have a feature to set a default date or time as the answer to a Google Form question.
As mentioned in the question, it IS possible to create a URL for the Google Form but, for a simple implementation, the Date and Time would not be dynamic; they would be the Date and Time on which the pre-fill was created.
For example:
prefill created on 20 March 2024: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSecqXJ2zEKK8siJ42wDqoR7_kYRtzB0K8gziFSOg4SaCUE9Kg/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.85836405=2004-03-20&entry.431994197=13:44
prefill created on 5 June 2024: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSecqXJ2zEKK8siJ42wDqoR7_kYRtzB0K8gziFSOg4SaCUE9Kg/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.85836405=2024-06-05&entry.431994197=15:11
A script can be used to create a dynamic Pre-filled URL (the second example was created by script) but it is unclear how this is to be communicated to a respondent.
In addition, though the pre-fill can include the Date and Time, there is nothing to stop a respondent from editing these fields.
